# How can I catch rejected Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

My code is as follows:

```
errorTest().then((result) => {

    try {
        console.log(result);
    }

    catch (err) {
        console.error("Error detected 1");
        console.error(err);
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error detected 2");
    console.error(err);
});

async function errorTest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject("my error");
    })
}
```

Currently, it prints "Error detected 2".

I would like to catch my error using try / catch such that the code prints "Error detected 1".

How do I modify my code to do this?

Comment: You're trying to catch error in success handler, see `then`'s [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Syntax)

Answer (score 5):

first when you declare `async` function that means you declare a function that returns a Promise.  so you don't need to warp it with new Promise

you can just do

```js
async function errorTest() {
  throw new Error("my error")
}
```

then you can catch it with try catch like this

```js
(async () =>{
  try{
    await errorTest()
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }

})()
```

then the full code will look like this

```js
async function errorTest() {
  throw new Error("my error")
}

(async () =>{
  try{
    await errorTest()
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an error is being thrown in the `errorTest` function, which happens first, that means that the `.catch` function is called instead of `.then`.

```
async function errorTest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("my error");
  })
}

try {
  var result = await errorTest()
  try {
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error detected 2");
    console.error(err);
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error detected 1");
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: This is aside from the other points about the use of async/await and promises mentioned by @Amit Wagner, which I felt were more general but valid educational points compared to answering the question at hand

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
//no need to make it async
function errorTest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject("my error");
    })
}

async function test(){
  try{
    await errorTest();
    try{
      console.log(result);
      //try some syncronous task.
    }
    catch(e){
      console.error("Error detected 1");
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    //if promise returned by errorTest() is rejected; rejected value: err 
    console.error("Error detected 2");
    console.error(err);
  }
}

test(); //this also returns a promise though.
```

Hope, this helps.